# Network drop status

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, system-configuration

I want to get notified where ever there is a network drop in application. Iam using Reachability for getting notified,when there is no internet but iam not getting any notification when iam connected to both Ethernet and WIFI,and any one it get disconnected and other is connected ,Please help iam stuck on it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little bit too much work for this simple task, but it's one way for you to get your work done. Try [Firebase Offline Capabilities](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/offline-capabilities.html).

It simply detects network drops and notifies you, plus, it's fast and simple to integrate.

Comment: I need it for Cocoa not for cocoatouch @nipuna H Hearth